# How can I find the origin of a vmmem process

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I use WSL2 and Docker Desktop for development. After stopping all Docker containers, stopping Docker Desktop, and shutting down all WSL distributions, I'm under the impression that there shouldn't be any VMs still running, but there is still one `vmmem` process remaining.

[image: vmmem process]

Hyper-V Manager says that there are no running VMs, and `Get-VM` in Powershell returns nothing.

How do I find where this VM is coming from so that I can shut it down?

Edit: ProcessExplorer output:
[image: ProcessExplorer]

Edit: `wsl -l -v` output:

```
PS C:\Users\flagr> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

Comment: Please see if this post helps you:  https://superuser.com/questions/1559170/how-can-i-reduce-the-consumption-of-the-vmmem-process

Comment: @John Unfortunately, none of the answers in that post help. WSL and Docker are both shut down entirely, and the Hyper-V Manager doesn't show any running VMs.

Comment: What does [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) say?

Comment: @Ramhound I added a screenshot of ProcessExplorer to the main post.

Comment: Are you by chance on an Insiders Preview build of Windows?  You performed the shutdown command on WSL, correct?

Comment: @Ramhound I am. I think that's a requirement for WSL2. I've run `wsl --shutdown`. That's the command you mean, right?

Comment: @Omegastick - That is false; WSL2 has been around since 1909.  I am suspecting perhaps a memory leak of some kind.  As a reminder WSL2 while using virtualization does not actually use Hyper-V since it’s supported on Windows 10 Home; Yes; That’s the command; I assume a Restart (or shift shutdown) clears up the process?

Comment: For kicks and giggles can you run **wsl -l -v** and provide the output (before that reboot)

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, I might look at getting off the insider build then. I added the output of `wsl -l -v` to the main post. Docker Desktop (and maybe WSL?) run on startup, so there are immediately a few `vmmem` processes when I start my PC up. I can see what happens if I disable them though.

Comment: My recommendation would be to either use 20H2 or wait for 21H1 to be released.  However, there isn’t a guarantee, this behavior isn’t [necessarily](https://blog.simonpeterdebbarma.com/2020-04-memory-and-wsl/) normal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at moving back onto the release preview channel.

Comment: @omegastick Have you been successful eventually? I am running on WSL2 (Kernel 5.1.0.102.1) and Windows 10 22H2. I often have the same behavior where all Hyper-V VMs are off and all WSL instances are stopped, but the vmmem process still takes up to 70% CPU. I observed that even though WSL says all instances are stopped, the Docker Client may send the "WSL2 backend stoppped unexpectedly" message 10-15mins after I stopped all instances. And when this message pops up, the CPU load goes down.